# Joint PDF (or MGF) of random sums

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, binary-data, matrix, moment-generating-function

I am interested in finding the joint PDF of two sums of random variables. Let:

- $\textbf{Z} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    {{z_1}} \\ 
    {{z_2}} 
  \end{array}} \right] = \textbf{D}\textbf{X}$
- $\textbf{X} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    {{x_1}} \\ 
    {{x_2}} 
  \end{array}} \right]$ be a vector of independent exponential random variables
- $\textbf{D} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    {{d_{11}}}&{{d_{12}}} \\ 
    {{d_{21}}}&{{d_{22}}} 
  \end{array}} \right]$ be a binary random matrix

Basically, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are random sums of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Due to the randomness of $\textbf{D}$, the entries of $\textbf{Z}$ can be partially correlated, fully correlated and uncorrelated.
How can I express the joint PDF of $f_{z_1,z_2}(z_1,z_2)$?
I would like to start with the joint moment generating function $\mathcal{M}_{z_1,z_2}(s_1,s_2)$ but have no idea where to start.

The idea is to start with two random variables and then expand to more further on.
I would appreciate any help or guiding points.

Comment: What do you mean by "fully correlated", $d_{12}=1$?

Comment: Here by "fully correlated" I meant to say that for instance, when all entries of $\textbf{D}$ are ones, _both_ $z_1$ and $z_2$ will be equal to $x_1+x_2$. For that particular instance, althought $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent, $z_1$ and $z_2$ will be the same, which I (hopefully correctly) termed "fully correlated".

Comment: What's the joint distribution for the entries in $\mathbf{D}$?

Comment: The entries of $\textbf{D}$ are independent, and take values $1$ with probability $\Pr[d_{ij}=1]=\exp(-\gamma_0/\bar \gamma_{ij})$ and $0$ with $\Pr[d_{ij}=0]=1-\exp(-\gamma_0/\bar \gamma_{ij})$, where $\gamma_0$ is some threshold. Also it holds that $d_{ii}=1$.